# What's the scope of a lock in Spring Data JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, locking

When using Spring Data's `JpaRepository`, if the `findOneById(...)` method is annotated with `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` (or any other), what's the scope of the lock, i. e. how long is it active for? Only while the select query executes, or until the transaction ends?

P.S.: What if the calling method is annotated with `@Transactional`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JPA 2.1 specification (emphasis mine):

> Pessimistic locking guarantees that once a transaction has obtained a pessimistic lock on an entity instance:
>
> - no other transaction (whether a transaction of an application using the Java Persistence API or any other transaction using the underlying resource) may successfully modify or delete that instance **until the transaction holding the lock has ended**.

Since this is the mechanism used by Spring Data JPA the lock is held until the end of the transaction.

Comment: That makes sense. I think I got confused by the [JavaDoc for `@Lock`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Lock.html), which just talked about "the query".